# Downloading Bootstrap's Navigation Bar Only

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstraps' framework but only for the navigation bar. I have a client who has a menu that has lots of dropdowns, so I figured using Bootstraps' was the most painless way to do it. When I tried downloading only the required CSS/JS/jquery components (I used tutorials found in stack overflow responses to the same issue from years ago), but when I do that some of the CSS styles are missing. The JS functionality works fine, but the navigation links (with class names like nav-link and nav-item) don't have the proper styles on them and the layout looks broken. It seems like there's something I'm missing. I'm assuming it has something to do with alpha vs. beta versions, but I'm not sure? Any advice would be great since I feel like overwriting all of those Bootstrap styles just for a navigation bar wouldn't be very sustainable.

**edit**: I'm adding screenshots to prove that I actually did research this problem and tried multiple methods before reaching out on here. I've been coding for over a year and never had to post a question here before, sorry for the late addition of screenshots.

[The navbar working perfectly fine with the Bootstrap CDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8YCG.png)

[The navbar breaking after customizing & downloading the code from Bootstrap's website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh7ys.png)

[Another screenshot of the broken navbar. This is why I said it seems like something from the CSS is missing on Bootstrap's end because the functionality works, but the layout/styles are broken.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyDRA.png)

Comment: Do you have the correct url to the bootstrap css file either offsite or onsite? Try if it works by adding this file to your `<head>` in the html: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">` (and do you have any console errors in the inspector?)

Comment: I think maybe I wasn't clear in my original post, hence all the downvotes :/ Sorry... It does work when I link directly to the Bootstrap framework. What I'm trying to do is extract only the code for the navbar since I don't need the entire Bootstrap framework. It works when I use the CDN link, but when I tried to download the code from Bootstrap with only the CSS, JS & components needed for the navbar, it breaks.

Comment: A few years back it was possible to download a subset of Bootstrap from the website, you could tick off the components you needed (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/). They have now removed this. You could compile a subset of the css by downloading the source files (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/#source-files) instead of the compiled files, and edit out everything you don't need from the file /scss/bootstrap.scss and then run the compile process with one of the npm scripts (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup)

Answer (score 3):

I ended up figuring this out. The problem is that Bootstrap doesn't offer customized compiled files for Bootstrap 4, only for 3.4. Between 3.4 and 4, there must have been a change in the way that classes like .nav-link and .nav-item are styled, which was causing the code to break. So to keep the code for the navbar from Bootstrap 4 that I'd already built, I made a list of all the class & ID names, went through Bootstrap 4's main CSS, and pulled out all of the corresponding classes. For organization's sake, I put those in a separate CSS file. Then I removed the CDN, linked the new CSS file that I made with only the classes for navigation, and made sure to include the most recent Bootstrap JS CDN (I used their link, no need to search through all of the JS too).

I'll add a codepen link to my solution later on today, because I'd imagine that I'm not the only person running into this problem when trying to isolate Boostrap's CSS for the navigation bar only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a navigation bar only use this:

```
html:
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">name of link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">name of link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">name of link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
js:
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the CSS problem. I guess she has to compile her cherrypicked CSS herself and that's why it didn't work out of the box. Which was what she ended up doing, but manually instead.